# Add 2 of the Same Fragments to the Same Container

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to, as you can see in the title, add 2 of the same fragments to the same container. I'm using a fragmentransaction to add my fragment. It works the first time, but when I try to add a second fragment, the fragment is replaced.

Here's my addition code:

```
public void addNewCategoryFragment(Category c) {
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction();
CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment(c.name);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_root, categoryFragment, String.valueOf(c.getID()));
fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Here's the xml that I'm trying to add the fragment to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/school"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="413dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:text="Submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/new_category_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:onClick="createNewCategory"
    android:text="New Category" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The tag value (`String.valueOf(c.getID())` in your case) has to be different. Is it?

Comment: Yes. The addNewCategoryFragment takes a Category as a argument. I'm using android-active-record as my ORM, so the getID is the id of the category in the sqlite database. Since it's the primary key, it's unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at a glance the java looks fine, it could be the layout. without knowing the layout of your fragment it's hard to say but my guess is it is just being covered up. Try putting a ScrollView around them or setting isScrollContainer to true like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/fragment_root"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="413dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:isScrollContainer="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

i'd also replace the "fill_parent" values with "match_parent" in the rest of the layout because fill_parent is deprecated